# Why doesn't javascript reset the cursor back to zero after allocating a size to the array

Tags: javascript

Taken an array with given size, when we try to push the elements into it, javascript pushes the elements post the allocated size. Shouldn't javascript reset the cursor back to zero and push the elements from the 0th index onwards?

```js
const arr = new Array(2);

arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);

console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: [No?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)

Comment: Don't use the Array constructor to create an empty array, that is just not JavaScript idiomatic and tells me you're coming from some other language. Instead, assign an empty array literal: `const arr = [];`.

Comment: @ArnavThorat Neither way creates a primitive type; arrays are always objects in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `new Array(2)`, it adds two elements, both with a value of `undefined`.

```js
const arr = new Array(2);
console.log(arr); // [undefined, undefined]
```

---

When you add the extra three, it will just continue adding to the array, instead of deleting the last three.

```js
const arr = new Array(2);

arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);

console.log(arr); // [undefined, undefined, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

If you, however, want to remove everything from the array, you can   set `length` to `0`.

```js
const arr = new Array(2);

arr.length = 0;
console.log(arr); // []
```

---

In summary, JavaScript will keep adding elements unless you explicitly delete them.

---

<sub>**Note:** Don't use `new Array()`. Instead, use an empty array (`[]`). This answer used the `Array()` constructor to match with the question.</sub>

Comment: I didn't know that you could do a `arr.length = 0` good to know

Comment: Ohh... I thought it's just allocating the memory for the 2 elements.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash  yeah, it's not like say capacity in a c++ list..

Comment: Don't use the Array constructor in the first place, and if you insist, remove the argument passed to it.

Comment: I've added an edit to the answer about that (I also personally think it's bad practice, and never use it). However, I only used it to match with the question.